# Is there a command that instantly produces a $0$ matrix?

Tags: matrices

I am getting tired of keeping a bunch of pre-made matrices on a notepad and keep copy and pasting them.

Is there a command that instantly fills an $n \times n$ matrix with entries $0$? Or something like an diagonal matrix function? I am not satisfied with a giant $0$ on the triangular parts either.

Comment: In the editor, or in your document ?

Comment: @percusse, is there a difference in result?

Comment: Some editors have the possibility to define such code-snippeds and insert them as needed. For example in `texstudio` they are called user macros.

Comment: I do all matrix-related stuff in Mathematica, and then after TeXForm@ -ing the matrix, I copy-paste it into my TeX editor. It uses `array` environment.

Comment: @Matsmath, I haven't used mathematica in a while. Actually i lost my copy after I upgraded my computer (thanks Apple...), but from what I remember you still have to type them out {{x,y},{y,z}} or filling them by hand.

Comment: I mean do you want to generate the result in the document or you want to see the filled matrix code in your editor?

Comment: @percusse well the answer below showed me the document. I guess you can show me the editor one.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{ct}
\newcounter{ict}
\newcommand{\zerorow}[1]{%
\forloop{ict}{1}{\value{ict}<#1}{0&}
0}
\newcommand{\zeromatrix}[2]{%
\begin{bmatrix}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct}<#1}{\zerorow{#2}\\}
\zerorow{#2}
\end{bmatrix}
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \zeromatrix{4}{3}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

In response to comment:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{ct}
\newcounter{ict}
\newcommand{\zerorow}[1]{%
\forloop{ict}{1}{\value{ict}<#1}{0&}
0}
\newcommand{\zeromatrix}[2]{%
\begin{bmatrix}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct}<#1}{\zerorow{#2}\\}
\zerorow{#2}
\end{bmatrix}
 }
\newcommand{\zeropartmatrix}[2]{%
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct}<#1}{\zerorow{#2}\\}
\zerorow{#2}
}   


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \zeromatrix{4}{3}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\zeropartmatrix{8}{2}\\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**and another edit**

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{ct}
\newcounter{ict}
\newcommand{\zerorow}[1]{%
\forloop{ict}{1}{\value{ict}<#1}{0&}
0}
\newcommand{\zeromatrix}[2]{%
\begin{bmatrix}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct}<#1}{\zerorow{#2}\\}
\zerorow{#2}
\end{bmatrix}
 }
\newcommand{\zeropartmatrix}[2]{%
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct}<#1}{\zerorow{#2}\\}
\zerorow{#2}
}   



\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \zeromatrix{4}{3}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\zeropartmatrix{8}{10}\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & \zeropartmatrix{1}{6} \\ \zeropartmatrix{4}{10}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was fun...

Comment: Wait what happens if I want to make all entries but one $0$? It seems like your new command doesn't allow that...

Comment: Sure, just adjust the command accordingly.

Comment: You have a for-loop that spans each row and column. How can I interrupt that?

Comment: See edited version.

Comment: In other words: don't interrupt, but repeat.

Comment: (And you can add another \zeropartmatrix after the interruption)

Comment: So basically just adjust the row/column and make the $0$ part smaller. Might work for corner entries and small ones. Kinda annoying if I have to do this for big ones with non-zero entry inside.

Comment: It's not that bad: see latest edit.